# How to pass process-ID of active process while using Jprobe

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module, jprobe

I'm trying to make a kernel module that takes the process-ID of an active process as an argument as module parameter, and tracks all the virtual addresses on which the target process faults.

While executing-
sudo ./module_name Parameter_1

What should be the Parameter_1 if I want to pass the ID of an active process.